# Simple Mod_rewrite

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, redirect

For some reason, all of the documentation for mod_rewrites I could find across the web were dealing with large queries, etc. I would just like to have a user enter in:

```
http://domain.com/page/faq
```

where they would be accessing just /faq.php

Sorry for my inexperience, but I hope you'll forgive me!
Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this rule in `.htaccess` in your document root, adding flags as necessary:

```
RewriteRule ^page/(.*) $1.php
```

Comment: Works perfect, fortunately no flags are needed for this one :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want only faq

```
RewriteRule ^page/faq.php faq.php
```

Otherwise Ignacio has the better solution.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah just for scaling, I'm going to use Ignacio's solution!